# How are link names referenced for gazebo/SetLinkState?

Tags: gazebo, simulation, simulator-gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In trying to use gazebo/SetLinkState I can't seem to figure out what to call the links to get gazebo to recognize them. I use the names I see published on "/gazebo/link_states". But everytime I use a link name that I know exists, it always replies with:

```
SetLinkState: link [My/Link/Name/Here_link] does not exist
```

I've tried many permutations including prefixing the link name with the model/robot name like:

```
Robot_Name/My/Link/Name/Here_link
```

to no avail.

TLDR: **How are link names referenced? What is the magic formula for getting gazebo to recognize link names?**

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10075/how-are-link-names-referenced-for-gazebo/setlinkstate?/) by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2743 on 2011-05-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It turns out the scope token for models is `'::'` so to get it to work, the link has to be referenced using a string like:

```
Robot_Name::My/Link/Name/Here_link
```

Currently the /gazebo/link_states topic does not publish the root scope (e.g. Robot_Name:: ) but this has been patched and the scope will be published along with the name in "Electric Turtle".

A patch for gazeboros in diamondback is available [here](http://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/raw-attachment/ticket/4972/scopedName.patch).

---

Originally posted by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) with karma: 2743 on 2011-05-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) on 2011-06-02**:
Next admin that sees this: Could you please mark this as the answer?